# How to get task bar to show over kiosk mode

Tags: chromium, kiosk

So I'm putting together a prototype here and have the apps I want to run in chromium kiosk mode which makes things look nice and smooth. But I want to use only mouse and no keyboard to select things including exiting the kiosk mode in chromium. There appears to be no way to do this without a keyboard.
So I thought of auto showing the top task bar that you can then switch to another app or close the window.
Does anyone know how to have that bar autoshow when chromium is in kiosk mode?  or maybe there is another way to have a mouse exit to desktop or close app in a similar way to ALT+F4.

Cheers in advance.

Comment: It seems the only way I can demo this and get it doing what I want is to use a wireless keyboard and use the ALT+F4 command to come out of chromium.  There appears to be no way to get a mouse to send this command or show the task bar at the top.   Kiosk mode clearly does not allow this with a mouse.

Comment: Is there a way to turn the middle mouse button into alt+f4 command?